# Parsing complex JSON object and extracting array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello im trying to parse this json object and get "results" array only. "results" array has properties so bunch of item starts with "property_id" and goes like this. here is what i tried so far;

```
def process_similar_list(response_json):
    
dataframe_list = []

for l in response_json['data']['home']['related_homes']:

    _temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l, orient='index').T

    dataframe_list.append(_temp_df)

return pd.concat(dataframe_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

[image: example list]

and returned error is like this;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-122-c0a7104717a6> in <module>
  ----> 1 df_properties_similar_list = process_similar_list(response_json=property_similar_list)
  2 df_properties_similar_list

 <ipython-input-111-c54f548650dc> in process_similar_list(response_json)
 22 
 23         # convert each listing to dataframe
 ---> 24         _temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(l, orient='index').T
 25 
 26         # append to dataframe list for all listings

 ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
 1235             if len(data) > 0:
 1236                 # TODO speed up Series case
 -> 1237                 if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
  1238                     data = _from_nested_dict(data)
  1239                 else:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

**The main thing is i want to display this results array as like this**
[image]

Comment: is it possible to post some of your response json as a sample?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you've drilled into the dict too far - Pandas DataFrame.from_dict(someDict, orient='index') is looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
someDict = {"someIndexLikeValue1":{"key1":"value11",
                    "key2":"othervalue12"},
"someIndexLikeValue2":{"key1":"value21",
                    "key2":"othervalue22"}}
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(someDict, orient="index"))

                        key1          key2
someIndexLikeValue1  value11  othervalue12
someIndexLikeValue2  value21  othervalue22
```

To do a one row dataframe with a dict that has an outer key (which is what I think you're doing), you need something like:

```
someOneRowDict = {"someOuterKey":{"someIndexLikeValue1":{"key1":"value11",
                    "key2":"othervalue12"}}}
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(someOneRowDict["someOuterKey"], orient="index"))

                       key1          key2
someIndexLikeValue1  value11  othervalue12
```

or to go one level deeper, you need to transform, as you've done:

```
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(someOneRowDict["someOuterKey"]["someIndexLikeValue1"], orient="index").T)

      key1          key2
0  value11  othervalue12
```

So I think what you've done is the equivalent of

```
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(someOneRowDict["someOuterKey"]["someIndexLikeValue1"]["key1"], orient="index"))
```

which gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```